# Analytical solution for an equation with both $\alpha$ and $\cos \alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

I am wondering if there is an analytical solution for $\alpha$ from the following equation:

$$C_1+\frac{C_2}{\alpha}=\frac{C_3}{1-cos(\alpha)} $$

Parameters $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$ are constant.

Edit: In case of no analytical solution, how about polynomial approximation or any other type of approximation?

Comment: The title is slightly different from the question. Should it be: "Analytical solution for an equation with both $\alpha$ and $\color{red}{\cos{\alpha}}$" ? Other than that, I doubt that a closed-form solution exists in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @projectilemotion - yes, I corrected it - thank you!

Comment: I have a strong feeling that doesn't have  a analytical solution because you can show that this equation is equivalent to $cos(\alpha) = P(\alpha)/Q(\alpha)$ where $P,Q$ are polynomials in $\alpha$. And this is a transcendental equation

Comment: @RafaelWagner - thanks for your comment. How about approximation?

Comment: Use $\cos(\alpha) = \sum_{i}(-1)^{i}\alpha^{2i}/((2i)!)$